# Public static fields in classes in java

Tags: java, burp

I'm developing a Burp Suite extension.

I have a class BurpExtender, it has public static field.

```
public class BurpExtender implements IBurpExtender, IContextMenuFactory{

    private IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks;
    public static PrintWriter stdout;
    public static IExtensionHelpers helpers;
    ...
    @Override
        public void registerExtenderCallbacks(IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks) {

            this.callbacks = callbacks;
            this.helpers = callbacks.getHelpers();
            PrintWriter stdout = new PrintWriter(callbacks.getStdout(), true);

            callbacks.setExtensionName("REQUESTSENDER");
            callbacks.registerContextMenuFactory(BurpExtender.this);
            stdout.println("Registered");

        }

    public List<JMenuItem> createMenuItems(final IContextMenuInvocation invocation) {
        List<JMenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new MyAction());
        menuItemList.add(item);
        return menuItemList;
    }
```

and in this file i have another class MyAction:

```
private class MyAction extends AbstractAction{
    public MyAction(){
        super("Name");
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Here i want to use BurpExtender.helpers, but i cant figure out, how to.
        //BurpExtender.stdout doesnt work here. Dunno why, NullPoinerException.
    }
}
```

I had another solution, when i tryed to do smth like JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("123") {...} result it the same

Comment: U need to initialise the static variable

Comment: You don't know but did you search what was that NullPointerException? This is THE exception you will encounter the most.

Comment: Ofcourse i init helpers and stdout in BurpExtender

Comment: **1** I don't see any initialisation, so if you do it in a Constructor, you need to be sure you build one instance before the action is used. **2** a NPE tell you that you have a `null` in stdout

Comment: Simple, is there `"Registered"` in your output ? If not, then you never initialise it. Since this is done in a registerXXX method, this might not be done. Always check the value of a static instance if you initialise with an instance method (since this might never happen)

Comment: Oh, I am an idiot. i init stdout as local var in  registerExtenderCallbacks. Lost 2 hours, lol

Answer (score 1):

You will need need to initialize the `helper` and `stdout` objects in your `BurpExtender` class.

Since these are static fields, an *appropriate* place would be to initialize them when declaring them or inside a static block in your class.

For Example:

> 1. While declaring them:

```
public static PrintWriter stdout = System.out;
public static IExtensionHelpers helpers = new ExtensionHelperImpl();// something like this.
```

> 2. Or inside a static block

```
public static PrintWriter stdout;
public static IExtensionHelpers helpers;

static {
    stdout = System.out;
    helpers = new ExtensionHelperImpl();// something like this.
}
```

Without this initialization, the `stdout` and `helpers` references will be pointing to `null`. This causes a NullPointerException when you try to use 
`BurpExtender.stdout` or `BurpExtender.helpers` in your other classes.

> **Update**

In your `MyAction` class declare a reference to hold the `IContextMenuInvocation invocation` object. Some thing like this:

```
private class MyAction extends AbstractAction{
    private IContextMenuInvocation invocation;

    public MyAction(IContextMenuInvocation invocation){
        super("Name");
        this.invocation = invocation;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Here you can use BurpExtender.helpers and IContextMenuInvocation invocation also.
        BurpExtender.helpers.doSomething();
        invocation.invoke();// for example..
    }
}
```

Then inside your outer class, change the `createMenuItems` method like this:

```
public List<JMenuItem> createMenuItems(final IContextMenuInvocation invocation) {
    List<JMenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new MyAction(invocation));// this is the change
    menuItemList.add(item);
    return menuItemList;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If a wont make it static, is there a way to use private/public fields from BurpExtension class in another? If i make MyAction inner?

Comment: Yes, _non-static_ inner classes *WILL* have access to the _non-static_ private and public fields declared in the outer class.

Comment: In (actionPerformed) i need to use (IContextMenuInvocation invocation). Is it possible to use it and BurpExtender.helpers?